# What to use to refactor the javascript / jQuery of a web application to use require.js and jasmine

Tags: javascript, jquery, refactoring, requirejs

I hope this question is not too general, but i haven't found any good tutorial on how to do the transition from standard javascript / jQuery code to modular / tested code.
Mmy new task is the complete refactoring of the javascript of our wordpress plugin. 
Our current code is standard jQuery code, thrown all into a file, with checks on the existance of dom elements to understand on what page we are in and attach the correct event handlers. 
My goal is simply to write more manteinable and clear code, and introduce tests in the process.
My approach would be:

- Try to modularize code in separate files (one file for each page) and use require.js to load  only the required code.
- write some tests with jasmine/sinon and try to adapt the esisting code so that the tests pass

Have you got any other suggestions/best practice?
Can you share some example on how you approached similar tasks?
I was thinking about bringing in an mvc framework but if i can stick to standard jQuery code i think it's easier for the development team because it doesn't add complexity

Comment: use yepnope included in modernizr

Comment: from a caching perspective, isn't it better to try and keep as much JS code in one file as possible?  I would think performance might be impacted negatively if you have multiple JS files - see [Best Practices for Speeding Up Your Web Site](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html) for more info

Comment: @ZackMacomber with require.js you combine all dependencies in a single file that is loaded asyincronously

Comment: ah ha - I see - haven't worked with require.js but looks very nice for managing multiple scripts.

Comment: I'm going to offset these -1's with a +1 because I think you've asked a good question that could help other developers (like myself) that need to do similar things in javascript/jQuery...

Comment: @ZackMacomber i've asked the question because i didn't find a tutorial online or an article on how to do the transition